# How can I detect enclosed areas in an arbitrary set of overlapping lines

Tags: collision-detection, algorithm

I have game where there can be arbitrary lines, these lines can overlap. I want to find out first if there are any enclosed shapes created by overlapping lines, and then I want to fill the enclosed shape.

The best guess I have at doing this comes from this other post: [determine if a set of tiles on a grid forms and enclosed shape](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/73722/determine-if-a-set-of-tiles-on-a-grid-forms-an-enclosed-shape). From what I can gather this would be, given a graph you can detect loops. However I can't quite figure out how to construct the graph from my data.

Is this a good way to go about solving this problem? And if so, any pointers on how I might get there given a list of collisions?

[image: zipper game]

Answer (score 2):

Hello and welcome to the site!

Here are some hindsights about how to construct a graph from your data:

- The collisions are the nodes of your graph.
- Each collision is bound to at least two lines (the two crossing, making the collision).

Then, each node is connected to all the others node having a line in common.

For example, the top collision in your image (let's call it **Node A**) is bound to the two green lines. On the left green line, there's another collision (**Node B**) with a pink line ; same thing on the right green line and another pink line (**Node C**). So we can start to build the graph with **Node A** being linked to **Node B** and **Node C**, since both of these two share a line with **Node A** (respectively the left and green ones). However, there is not link between **Node B** and **Node C** since they don't share a line.
Now do the same with your other collisions, then apply the graph magic from the other post, and you're done!

Comment: Hey! Sorry, I've been super busy with other stuff, I can understand the connections etc. I'm just struggling to _actually build_ a coherent representation of the graph from the list of collision nodes.