# Detect if a chain of tiles form an enclosed shape/contour

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking to determine if in a tilemap if a set of tiles of same color in a chain (either right next to cardinally, or diagonal) is forming a closed shape and to detect the tiles inside the said shape.

To clarify further, a player will step on a tile to give it color, if the player walks around the tilemap forming a shape with the same color of tiles, I'll need to know if that chain is enclosed, and the tiles inside of it.

I have read the previous similar question to mine, but it focuses more on sides of the edge and filling the tiles inside the shape, whereas I want to detect if any enclosed shape is formed from a chain of same colored tiles.

Comment: The algorithms described at the [linked question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/73722/39518) can be used to "detect if any enclosed shape is formed from a chain of same coloured tiles". Can you explain how you've tried applying the existing answers, where you've run into difficulty, or how exactly they depart from what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Once the player steps on a new tile and colours it, examine the neighbourhood (8 tiles around it). Find the tiles that are of the player's colour, sort out early rejections (if there are 2 or fewer, you cannot possibly have anything enclosed yet), any tiles that are not of that colour are potential inside/outside candidates.

Create a copy of your tilemap, that only stores two types of tile - "player colour" tile and "any other" tile and try flood filling from any of the candidate tiles (there might be a heuristic for this) If after the flood fill, all candidate tiles got flood filled, you do not have an enclosed area (there's a leak). Otherwise you have now a set of tiles that got flood filled, that's one area, and another set of tiles that didn't get flood filled.

Good news is that one of these is exactly the set of the tiles inside of your shape, bad news I am not sure how to distinguish between the two.
I know that size cannot be used as you could have enclosed a huge area taking up most of the field. Maybe somehow check the edges of the field and see whether they are flood filled or not, and whatever touches the edges is the "outside"?

I hope this will get you a bit of the way there.